# NoClassDefFoundError: UnsupportedFileFormatException while using apache poi to write to an excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to write to an excel(.xlsx) file using Apache poi, I included the apache poi dependencies in my pom.xml file. But I am getting the following exception in execution.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/UnsupportedFileFormatException
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at test.ExcelWriting.main(ExcelWriting.java:24)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.UnsupportedFileFormatException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        ... 13 more
```

The code and pom.xml is specified as follows.

I am getting the exception in the following line.

```
XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);
```

Code:

```
package test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelWriting {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File myFile = new File("/home/sabra/workspace/test/src/main/resources/test.xlsx");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);

        // Finds the workbook instance for XLSX file
        XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook (fis);

        // Return first sheet from the XLSX workbook
        XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);

        Map<String, Object[]> data = new HashMap<String, Object[]>();
        data.put("7", new Object[] {7d, "Sonya", "75K", "SALES", "Rupert"});
        data.put("8", new Object[] {8d, "Kris", "85K", "SALES", "Rupert"});
        data.put("9", new Object[] {9d, "Dave", "90K", "SALES", "Rupert"});

        // Set to Iterate and add rows into XLS file
        Set<String> newRows = data.keySet();

        // get the last row number to append new data          
        int rownum = mySheet.getLastRowNum();         

        for (String key : newRows) {

            // Creating a new Row in existing XLSX sheet
            Row row = mySheet.createRow(rownum++);
            Object [] objArr = data.get(key);
            int cellnum = 0;
            for (Object obj : objArr) {
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
                if (obj instanceof String) {
                    cell.setCellValue((String) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Boolean) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Boolean) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Date) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Date) obj);
                } else if (obj instanceof Double) {
                    cell.setCellValue((Double) obj);
                }
            }
        }

        // open an OutputStream to save written data into XLSX file
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        myWorkBook.write(os);
        myWorkBook.close();
    }
}
```

Pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.11-beta2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think You'r missing some classes "UnsupportedFileFormatException"

try to change the poi versions to the same and dont use the 3.11-beta2

You can use both in version 3.12
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi

Comment: The issue was that I was missing some classes. Changing both versions to 3.12 fixed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code using the Jar Libs and not maven (see the images of project) and it worked fine. So like Athi said, you are missing some libs or the type of your file is not a xlsx.

[image]

[image]

PS: I just changed this line of code 
from

```
 File myFile = new File("/home/sabra/workspace/test/src/main/resources/test.xlsx");
```

to

```
File myFile = new File("test.xlsx");
```

Comment: The file type is xlsx, I can open it through LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu. The issue was that I was missing some classes and Athis' solution fixed it. Thanks.